# Solve (ln(1+x))^2 = ln(1+x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How I solve this equation:
$$(\ln(1+x))^2 = \ln(1+x)$$

If $A>0$, then $\ln(A) = B \iff A= e^B$

$(\ln(1+x))^2 = \ln(1+x) \iff  \frac{(\ln(1+x))^2}{\ln(1+x)}  = 1 \iff \ln(1+x) = 1 \iff 1+x= e \iff x= e-1$

What the error?

Comment: You can use MathJax to nicely format your math.

Comment: solve $a^2=a$ with $a=\ln\left(1+x\right)$

Comment: @Mastrem Don't be so trivial. MathJax does not format math. It formats text.

Comment: @Alephnull Oh, I'm sorry. Still, someone thought it was a good idea :) Learned something new today then.

Answer (score 4):

$${ \left( \ln { \left( x+1 \right)  }  \right)  }^{ 2 }=\ln { \left( x+1 \right)  } \\ \ln { \left( x+1 \right)  } \left( \ln { \left( x+1 \right)  } -1 \right) =0\\ \ln { \left( x+1 \right)  } =0\quad \Rightarrow \quad x+1=1\Rightarrow x=0\quad \\ \quad \ln { \left( x+1 \right)  } -1=0\quad \Rightarrow \ln { \left( x+1 \right) =1\quad \Rightarrow x={ e }-1 }  $$

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing by $\log(1+x)$ when $x\neq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\{\log(1+x)\}^2&=\log(1+x),\\
\log(1+x)&=1,\\
1+x&=e,\\
x&=e-1.
\end{align*}
If $x=0$, the equation holds trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Well:
$$\ln(x+1)^2=\ln(1+x)$$
one option is $\ln(1+x)=0\implies x=0$. Otherwise, divide both sides by $\ln(1+x)$:
$$\ln(1+x)=1\implies1+x=e\implies x=e-1$$

Comment: dividing  both side to $ln(x+1)$ is wrong hence $x=0$ is a solution

Comment: @haqnatural Well, I said only to divide when $x\neq 0\implies \ln(1+x)\neq0$

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling gives $\ln(1+x)=1 \implies 1+x=e$ .